# Инструмент тестирования для Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, тестирование, поиск-библиотек

Знаю, что для Delphi 2010 и более поздних версий есть DUnit. Искала что-нибудь подобное для Delphi 7, но не нашла. Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли какие-нибудь готовые решения для тестирования, которые можно можно использовать с Delphi 7 ? Возможно какая-нибудь переделка DUnit, или что-нибудь простое самодельное, или наоборот, что-то универсальное?

Только начала изучать тестирование и единственным вариантом для Delphi 7 вижу как-то включить тесты в основной проект, так ли это?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На гитхабе уже много лет есть вот такой курируемый список инструментов/библиотек для тестирования Delphi - [awesome-delphi#unit-testing](http://github.com/Fr0sT-Brutal/awesome-delphi#unit-testing)

Там можно найти [старую версию DUnit](http://dunit.sourceforge.net/), которая вполне работает начиная аж с Delphi 5.